# CSS Columns and equal content

Tags: css

I want to utilize CSS3 Columns around my site as it on wide pages provides a better UX for the users. However if I use CSS3 Columns, sometimes the left column is full (lets say 20 lines of text) and the right side only have2 lines of text. Can I with pure css3 (maybe Flexbox) make it have equal amount of content? Or do I need JS to fix this?

Beaware I'm not talking about equal height, but equal amount of content :)

Comment: Wouldn't "equal amount of content" imply "equal height"?

Comment: @rnevius: no. If you Google "equal height" you only get results for divs in equal heights (backgrounds and such). I'm interested in "equal text/content".

Comment: you should consider using the twitter bootstrap framework or something similar.

Comment: @gldraphael: Why? Do they have a solution for this issue since you mention that framework?

Comment: @MortenHjort you don't need js for this - but please provide what you currently have - a sample case - I think I know what your problem is and I can make it work for you with CSS only. But need your code first.

Comment: @gldraphael: I cant find their solution to this issue? Please make a deeplink if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify a `height` property.

From the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts#Height_Balancing):

> The CSS3 Column specification requires that the column heights must be
>   balanced: that is, the browser automatically sets the maximum column
>   height so that the heights of the content in each column are
>   approximately equal.
>
> However, in some situations it is also useful to set the maximum
>   height of the columns explicitly, and then lay out content starting at
>   the first column and creating as many columns as necessary, possibly
>   overflowing to the right. Therefore, if the height is constrained, by
>   setting the CSS height or max-height properties on a multi-column
>   block, each column is allowed to grow to that height and no further
>   before adding new column. This mode is also much more efficient for
>   layout.

Comment: Thanks, but this wont work in a RWD-world. Only if all content and sizes are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was a padding-bottom which messed it up. When I remove that it spreads out nicely. Strange!